# What holds low temperature the best for bread baking?

Tags: bread, proofing

I would like to follow this [recipe](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/7061/salt-rising-bread/). However, I am a little wary about setting my crock pot for 7-12 hours like it says. I am unsure it can keep the 110 F temperature. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: A sous vide machine would keep a constant temperature. Why do you not think your crock pot could hold the temperature?

Comment: @kccu I thought a crock pot steadily rose the temperature, the settings just changed the speed at which it rose

Comment: You could do a test run by just putting some water in your crock pot and measuring the temperature over time. Or you could cycle your crock pot on and off to keep it around 110 if you'll be home for 7-12 hours.

Comment: Any crock pot that I have used gets _way_ hotter than 105 on the warm setting.  I agree that probably isn't a good option and I'm not sure why the recipe would recommend that unless you're manually cycling the crock pot on and off. @kccu I think sous vide is the better option and could be an answer.  That's if you can find one that goes that low on temp.

Comment: my crock pot's three settings (HML) measure at 180, 135, and 113 F. you might be lucky, just measure it. you can also hack your crockpot to adjust the built-in temp settings or externally control it with something more precise.